# Where Can I find a good tutorial for IJG libjpeg

Tags: c, libjpeg, ijg

I need to do some work with this library and I'm finding the documentation at http://apodeline.free.fr/DOC/libjpeg/libjpeg.html to be deficient (incomplete function signatures, etc). Does anyone know of some other sides or have some example code illustrating common tasks?

[Edit]
I also found this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/637043/using-jpeglib-for-jpeg-compressed-byte-stream) with an example, but any others would be helpful.

Comment: Here's some well commented code https://github.com/LuaDist/libjpeg/blob/master/example.c

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try using [libjpeg](http://libjpeg.sourceforge.net/) library. Example how to use it is in [this blog](http://andrewewhite.net/lifetype/blog.php/the-white-blog/programming/2008/09/02/very-simple-jpeg-writer-in-c-c).

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what you're using, but we use the C++ wrapper at [Smaller Animals Software](http://www.smalleranimals.com/jpegfile.htm), and we're happy with it.  If nothing else, it might work as example code.

Comment: Sorry, looks like you're link didn't work.

Comment: Okay, I obviously messed up the editing.  Let's try just giving the link:
http://www.smalleranimals.com/jpegfile.htm
Sorry about that.

Comment: Well, yes, it *is* a link, but that’s what the (now closed) question asked for. This is not really any worse than the 9-upvote accepted answer, except that something on sourceforge has a better chance of staying around, and it’s in C. Given that context, I vote to leave it alone.

Comment: link is dead, next time listen