# extract/convert a jpeg image (from a buffer in memory) to rgb

Tags: c++, c, libjpeg, ppm

i am writing a c/c++ program and i need to take images from a buffer in the memory and transform in RGB, that is 3 components of the image. I was looking at the libjpeg library, but i didn't find any tutorial or example. 
thanks

Comment: This might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/639511/where-can-i-find-a-good-tutorial-for-ijg-libjpeg

Comment: You probably didn't search well enough, because a thirty second googling session pointed me to this: http://libjpeg.cvs.sourceforge.net/viewvc/libjpeg/libjpeg/example.c?view=markup

Comment: The first thing you should ask is: How are your images stored in the memory? If they are in bitmap format, you can write relative straight-ahead code to do that....

Comment: Can you clearly tell what your objective is? you want to transform a jpeg image to rgb image or something else?

Comment: thanks. Yes, i have a jpeg image (640x480, size about 40000 Bytes) in a buffer and i want to convert it into RGB format.